# How do I write these loops in ES6 vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new in ES6, how do I write this code in simplest and short form in ES6 vanilla?

```
ref8 = b.querySelectorAll("[class*='fileType-']");
for (l1 = 0, len9 = ref8.length; l1 < len9; l1++) {
  x = ref8[l1];
  ref9 = function () {
    var len10, n1, ref9, results;
    ref9 = x.classList;
    results = [];
    for (n1 = 0, len10 = ref9.length; n1 < len10; n1++) {
      k = ref9[n1];
      if (k.startsWith("fileType-")) {
        results.push(k);
      }
    }
    return results;
  }();
  for (m1 = 0, len10 = ref9.length; m1 < len10; m1++) {
    k = ref9[m1];
    x.classList.remove(k);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the elements to possibly have more than one class that starts with `fileType`, or only one?

Comment: Can you precise what part exactly doesn't work in vanilla ? And please... pay attention to your variable declarations if you don't want hard to find bugs to explode in your face.

Comment: [knock yourself out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: This already is ES6 compatible code (there is no "ES6 vanilla"). Maybe you meant that you'd like this minimized/obfuscated code turned into a more readable source code and possibly optimized?

Comment: My eyes hurts after seeing your variable names

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the the list of elements using [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). Get the list of classes, convert it to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), filtering it to items that start with `fileType-`, and then removing them from the classList:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class*='fileType-']")
  .forEach(el => {
    Array.from(el.classList)
      .filter(cls => cls.startsWith('fileType-'))
      .forEach(cls => el.classList.remove(cls));
  });
```

```css
.fileType-x {
  color: red;
}

.fileType-y {
  color: blue;
}

.fileType-z {
  color: purple;
}

.fileType-z2 {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="fileType-x">X</div>
<div class="someother class fileType-y">Y</div>
<div class="fileType-z fileType-z2">Z</div>
<div class="dummy">dummy</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only one class containing `fileType`, you can match it concisely with a regular expression, while iterating over the elements with `forEach`, and then remove the matched class name from the `classList` of the element:

```
b.querySelectorAll("[class*='fileType-']")
  .forEach((element) => {
    const { className } = element;
    const fileTypeClass = className.match(/(?:^| )(fileType-\S+)/)[1];
    element.classList.remove(fileTypeClass);
  });
```

Note that this utilizes `NodeList.prototype.forEach`, which doesn't exist in older browsers - if you want this to work on older browsers, `.call` `Array.prototype.forEach` instead:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  b.querySelectorAll("[class^='fileType-']"),
  (element) => {
    const { className } = element;
    const fileTypeClass = className.match(/(?:^| )(fileType-\S+)/)[1];
    element.classList.remove(fileTypeClass);
  }
);
```

(or include a polyfill for `NodeList.prototype.forEach`)

Comment: I'd avoid using regular expressions in this case. @OriDrori's answer using `startsWith()` in a conditional is better suited and safer.

Comment: @MihaiPotra Why do you think a regular expression isn't safe? If the HTML/attributes are malformed and the RE doesn't work, all bets are off, the `classList` may well fail too.

Comment: Regular expressions are expensive, especially for this scenario where even `str.indexOf('fileType-') != -1` would be the fastest operation, but `startsWith()` is more terse (and still fast).

Comment: Your `match()` call can also return `null` if an elemnet does not have a class name starting with "fileType-", which you're not handling. And lastly, regexp should be a last resort: https://medium.com/@liran.tal/node-js-pitfalls-how-a-regex-can-bring-your-system-down-cbf1dc6c4e02

Comment: The `[class*='fileType-']` selector ensures that the only elements matched will be ones that contain the substring `fileType-` somewhere in the class attribute. It's not hard at all to avoid catastrophic backtracking, but there aren't any nested quantifiers in this regex anyway.

Comment: Agreed. But it's very easy to mess up the regex provided, without solid in-depth knowledge of regular expressions. All I'm saying is that in scenarios such as this, it's easier, safer and better performance to do basic string operations than introducing the complexities of regex.